# Postgres Error 08001 (SQLCLIENT UNABLE TO ESTABLISH SQLCONNECTION) and the FOC1394 Error

Tags: postgresql

I use trigger after the update and insert one table to synchronize one table on one server with a foreign table on a different server.
My problem is that different servers can be down and I need my functions to be able to handle that (not with error).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.gapless_seq_update_forein()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

begin


update gapless_seq_b set drain=new.drain, end_batch=new.end_batch, 
file_name=new.file_name 
where seq=new.seq and lobid = new.lobid and neid = new.neid;

END IF;            

return new;
end;                
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 1):

easy solution (that is for some reason hard to google)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.gapless_seq_update_forein()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $function$

 begin


 update gapless_seq_b set drain=new.drain, end_batch=new.end_batch,                     
 file_name=new.file_name 
 where seq=new.seq and lobid = new.lobid and neid = new.neid;

 return new;

 exception when others THEN
        -- Do nothing.

 return new;
         END;


 $function$
 ;
```

note: my error is 08001 sqlclient_unable_to_establish_sqlconnection but for some reason it works only with "others"...

more here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-control-structures.html